# How to read this array from preg_match_all result?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this result from preg_match_all

```
preg_match_all('#mpeg"\],"Content-Length":\["(.*?)","(.*?)"#', $size,$out);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => mpeg"],"Content-Length":["697","3595701"
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 697
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3595701
        )

)
```

I tried to show the last value : 3595701 whit :

```
$size = $out[2][0];
```

But always is empty?, am I miss something ?

Comment: Show how you call `preg_match_all`.

Comment: sorry, I edit my question

Comment: How can `$out[2][0]` be empty if `print_r($out)` gives the result you've shown? It's something wrong with how you use this value, not with how you get it.

Comment: where does the input $size come from? What does it contain? I have a feeling preg_match could be the wrong tool here.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dumping the value of the `preg_match_all`, maybe dump the value of `$out` - I have a feeling your value resides in `$out[2]`.

Comment: Result of `preg_match_all` is the number of matches or `false`, but never an array. The OP have shown the contents of `$out`.